# Pandas subsetting doesnt seem to work based on Index in Python3.6

Tags: pandas

I have a weird problem. I do not know if its correct. I found this issue with python3.6

Click [link](https://github.com/jennybc/gapminder/raw/master/inst/gapminder.tsv) for the dataset

```
df = pd.read_csv("./data/gapminder.tsv",sep="\t")
```

The code below doesn't produce any error

```
subset = df[['country', 'pop']]
subset.head()
```

But if I try to subset based on index, I'm getting error

```
subset = df[[0,4]]
> KeyError: '[0 4] not in index'
```

Please find the details of the ipython error in the [link](https://gist.github.com/arun-siv/5bf2f93df6efed542ebcfef1291f069b)

Answer (score 1):

Need [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jennybc/gapminder/master/inst/gapminder.tsv'
df = pd.read_csv(url, sep="\t")
print (df.head())
       country continent  year  lifeExp       pop   gdpPercap
0  Afghanistan      Asia  1952   28.801   8425333  779.445314
1  Afghanistan      Asia  1957   30.332   9240934  820.853030
2  Afghanistan      Asia  1962   31.997  10267083  853.100710
3  Afghanistan      Asia  1967   34.020  11537966  836.197138
4  Afghanistan      Asia  1972   36.088  13079460  739.981106

subset = df[['country', 'pop']]
print (subset.head())
       country       pop
0  Afghanistan   8425333
1  Afghanistan   9240934
2  Afghanistan  10267083
3  Afghanistan  11537966
4  Afghanistan  13079460

subset = df.iloc[:, [0,4]]
print (subset.head())
       country       pop
0  Afghanistan   8425333
1  Afghanistan   9240934
2  Afghanistan  10267083
3  Afghanistan  11537966
4  Afghanistan  13079460
```